# How to fix truncated Tar file in linux console

Tags: linux, tar, file-corruption

On a remote server running Linux Ubuntu 16.04', I ran out of space while doing a tar file from a bunch of old .rar files (~150G), and now the end tar is 'corrupt'. That is when doing a `tar tf` I get:

```
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can I fix this corrupted tar?

I've tried to:

- delete the truncated file from the tar (`tar --delete -f mycorruptedtar.tar offendingfile.ext`)
- repair it by extracting the files that aren't corrupt and adding them to a new tar by doing

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(tar -tf mycorruptedtar.tar);
do
        if [ ! "$file" == "offendingfile.ext" ]
        then
                tar xf mycorruptedtar.tar $file
                tar rf newtar.tar $file --remove-files
                tar --delete -f mycorruptedtar.tar $file
        fi
done
```

- I also tried using a hex editor to remove the last part of the file which I assume is where lies the problem, but I chickened out because I didn't know exactly how or what to fix and I didn't want to worsen things.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the real problem? When you get `Unexpected EOF in archive`, `tar` has already unpacked what it could (all complete files and even bits of the truncated file). So, unlike a ZIP, the truncated tar is usable.

Comment: I want to fix the tar before adding the rest of the files I still need to add to the tar... Maybe another option would be to just make a new tar with the other files and keep this 'functioning corrupt tar'... I also wanted to know how to fix the file, if possible

Comment: Theoretically it should be possible to compute position of the end of the last good file, truncate the TAR there and append the end-of-archive marker. But IMHO de-tarring what you can and re-tarring it will be easier and less risky.

Comment: I agree with you advice. I was just wondering if there was an automated tool/method to help me fix the file task before setting up a new volume with enough space to do the 'de-tarring/re-tarring'.